# SecurityFilterChain - regexMatchers() for validating an endpoint which is similar in structure to other endpoints

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have three endpoints:

- GET /rest/file/{name}/{guid} - this one is secured with OAuth2 token
- GET /rest/file/task/{guid}
- GET /rest/file/{guid}

I need a Regex expression for Spring Security's SecurityFilterChain with OAuth2 Resource Server. It should catch the last endpoint but not the first two. Resource Server is already correctly configured for many other endpoints, so it's not a global issue but strictly Regex.

Examples:

- /rest/file/aaaaa/{guid} is validated for OAuth2 token
- /rest/file/task/{guid} is NOT validated for OAuth2 token
- /rest/file/{guid} is NOT validated for OAuth2 token

I see two approaches:

1. URL with path variable {name} which is not "task" and path variable {guid} after the {name} which matches GUID's structure
2. URL with path variable {name} which is not "task" and at the same time {name} does not match GUID structure

I came up with this but it always returns 403.

```
private static final String REGEX_GUID = "^[{]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}"
                    + "-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-)"
                    + "{3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[}]?$";

.regexMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/rest/file/^(?!task$)/" + REGEX_GUID)
```

Comment: Can you get away with just matching anything that doesn't contain any more slashes? So it'll match `/rest/file/anything` but not `/rest/file/anything/more`. That's a much easier regex :)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not solve the problem. That would match /rest/file/{guid} (which is wrong). Also it would not match /rest/file/task/{guid} (which is ok) and it would not match /rest/file/{name}/{guid} (which is wrong). Also I cannot change urls.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested it worked with:

```
private static final String REGEX_GUID = "[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}$";

.regexMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/rest/file/(?!.*task).*/" + REGEX_GUID)
```